# unable to mount ntfs filesystem after upgrading to windows 10 on dual boot system

Tags: mount, ntfs

I have a dual boot system - Ubuntu 14.04 and recently upgraded Windows 10 - running on a Dell Inspiron N5030 laptop.

Everything worked fine after the upgrade but a couple of days later I started getting the following error when trying to access the NTFS partitions on the system:

```
**Unable to mount 87 GB Volume**
**Error mounting /dev/sda9 at /media/shashi/2CB26F41501D3DCC: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/sda9" "/media/shashi/2CB26F41501D3DCC"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda9': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.**
```

I'm not a very experienced Ubuntu user so can't figure out what this means. Can someone tell me how to fix this? Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your issue is that you have Windows 10 in 'Quick Boot' or 'Fast Boot' mode.  Basically, Windows 10 is hibernating rather than fully shutting down.

You need to disable 'Quick Boot' or 'Fast Boot' in order to fully mount that partition.  There is a workaround to where you can mount it read-only, but that gets complicated.
See http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html for instructions.

Comment: Daniel, disabling 'Fast Boot' in Windows fixed the issue, the NTFS partitions now mount without a problem. Also, Windows 10 start up and shut down times have not increased appreciably after disabling 'Fast Boot'.

Comment: Remember, if this answer helped you you can mark it as accepted by clicking the checkbox below the vote counter. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.tenforums.com](http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/4189-fast-startup-turn-off-windows-10-a.html) to disable fast boot.

You can also run these commands

```
mkdir media/sd9
mount -t ntfs-3g -o rw /dev/sda9 /media/sd9
```

to read and write from the drive.